# Pass external workbook cell address as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change color of the active cell in Workbook1 and the same cell address in Workbook2.
For example if the active cell is A1 in Workbook1, the same cell address (A1) should be changed in Workbook2.

```vb
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)

Dim cellRef As Range
Set cellRef = ActiveCell

[Order Entry.xlsx].Dec2022.Range(" & cellRef.Address & ").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
End Sub
```

I get compile error and syntax error.

If I pass hardcoded address it works.

e.g.

```
Range("'[Order Entry.xlsx]Dec2022'!A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
```

So my problem must be with addressing the variable.

Comment: Tried r1c1 notation?

Answer (score 0):

Use full address - book().sheet().range()

```
Sub test1()
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    Workbooks("Order Entry.xlsx").Sheets("Dec2022").Range(ActiveCell.Address).Interior.Color = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. However, if the target excel is closed wrong cell is colored. I tried to open the excel using ` Workbooks.Open sPath & sFilename ` if not already open but didn't help. Anyway to "open excel", "color the right cell", "save n close" ? Thanks again

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449476/15035314